# I get error "Attempted to call method "generateUrl" on class" Symfony 2.6

Tags: php, forms, symfony, crud

After genarated Role CRUD (***console generate:doctrine:crud***), i'm trying to override Form by using RoleType,

but i get error :
 `Attempted to call method "generateUrl" on class "BISSAP\UserBundle\Form\RoleType".`

Part of CRUD - **RoleController.php**

```
public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Role();
        //$form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form   = $this->createForm(new RoleType(),$entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('role_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        return $this->render('BISSAPUserBundle:Role:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Part of routing - **role.yml**

```
role_new:
    path:     /new
    defaults: { _controller: "BISSAPUserBundle:Role:new" }

role_create:
    path:     /create
    defaults: { _controller: "BISSAPUserBundle:Role:create" }
    requirements: { _method: post }
```

Part of **RoleType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('role')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('groupRole',
                      'entity',
                       array(
                             'class'=>'BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\GroupRole',
                             'property'=>'name',
                             'query_builder' => function (\BISSAP\USerBundle\Entity\GroupRoleRepository $repository)
                             {
                                 return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c');
                                        //->where('c.parent = :parent')
                                        //->setParameter('parent', 19)
                                        //->add('c.name', 'ASC');
                             }
                            )
                      )
            ->add('Enregistrer', 'submit', array(
                'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'blabla')));
            //->add('groupRole');

    }
```

So, i don't understand, why generateUrl doesn't work?!

Comment: Use $this to refer to the current object. Use self to refer to the current class.

Comment: I know self:: on $variable, but i don't konw how use selff on function, can you give me PHP syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really strange ! It seems `$this` represents the `RoleType` instance and not the `RoleController`.

Try this :

```
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Role();
    $url = $this->generateUrl('role_create');

    $form = $this->createForm(new RoleType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $url,
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    return $this->render('BISSAPUserBundle:Role:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```